# jQuery this.html() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I'm reformatting some really bad HTML using jQuery.  I need to splice sibling `<font>` elements together.  I tried this code:

```
$('font+font').each(function() {
    this.html().appendTo( this.prev() );
    this.remove();
});
```

but it gave me this error: **TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.html()')**

---

Here's a sample of the HTML:

`<font>This fragment </font><font>is actually one element.</font>`

---

**Update**

I updated my code with `$(this)`, but it still isn't working.  When I run this code

```
$('font+font').each(function() {
    $(this).html().appendTo( $(this).prev() );
    $(this).remove();
});
```

I get this error: **TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(this).html().appendTo( $(this).prev() )')**

Comment: @Madmartigan - Hence "really bad HTML."  It's markup from the mid 90s.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that part. Yeah, I have to do that all the time with much much uglier code. Ancient ecommerce software with dated templates from the `spacer.gif` table layout days...

Comment: I recommend copying the elements themselves instead. `$("font + font").each(function() { $(this).contents().appendTo($(this).prev()).end().remove(); });`.

Comment: @pimvdb - very nice, but you need to use `.end().end()` in place of `.end()`.

Comment: Really? I'm only changing the set once.

Comment: @pimvdb - The first `.end()` in your code targets the content that was moved with `.contents()`.  Thus, your code deletes the appended contents as soon as they are moved.  A second `.end()` is needed to target the original `$(this)`.

Comment: @Brandon Lebedev: You're completely correct - thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. `this` has to be wrapped in a jQuery object, before you can use jQuery methods on it.
2. `.html()` returns a string. You cannot use jQuery methods on a string without wrapping. Use `$this.prev().append( $this.html() )` instead.
3. When using `$(this)` more than once, it's wise to store `$(this)` in a temporary variable. It's the convention to prefix jQuery objects with a dollar sign.

Code:

```
$('font+font').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.prev().append( $this.html() );
    $this.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 9):

When you use an each statement, it returns `this` as a DOM element, not a jQuery object. `.html()` must be called on a jQuery object. So the first part of your fix is to convert `this` into a jQuery element with the `$` symbol.

```
$(this).html(); //don't use this.html();
```

The second problem is that `html()` returns a string. You can't call `AppendTo()` on a string, only a jQuery object. Since you are working with `.html()` I'll assume that you want the string contents and not the full contents. If that were the case, Rob's answer is more appropriate.

```
this.textContent = $(this).prev().html() + this.textContent; // prepend siblings content
```

The final code ends up looking like this:

```
$('font+font').each(function() {
    this.textContent = $(this).prev().html() + this.textContent;
    $(this).prev().remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b6vLL37k/1

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `$(this)` not `this`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$(this)` for jQuery to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to fix your code. How about something like this:

```
 var text = '';
 $('font').each(function() {
   text += $(this).text();
 });
 console.log($('<p />').text(text));
```

Comment: If I understand your code, it doesn't splice siblings.  It splices every `<font>` element into a single element, which is not what I want to do.